# while(rs.next) database result

Tags: java, database

Why am I getting only the last result from the mysql database it doesn't matter that whatever elements are there in the db? How can I retrieve my all database rows?

Here`s the code:

```
package database;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class getData extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Setzen setze = new Setzen();
    int zeilen;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ausgaben","***","***");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ausgaben");
            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            zeilen = meta.getColumnCount();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                setze.setAusgaben(rs.getString("Ausgaben"));
                setze.setVom(rs.getString("vom"));
                setze.setPreis(rs.getString("Preis"));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(setze.getAusgaben());
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String data = "{\"sEcho\":" + 3 + ",\"iTotalRecords\":" + zeilen + ", \"iTotalDisplayRecords\":" + zeilen + ",\"aaData\":[["+"\""+setze.getAusgaben()+"\""+","+"\""+setze.getVom()+"\""+","+"\""+setze.getPreis()+"\""+"]]}";
        System.out.println(data);
        out.print(data);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving all the results into one object, `setze`.

It looks like you want to collect all the results and return them as some kind of JSON structure. You should try something like this, using the [json.org Java package](http://www.json.org/java/). It avoids the huge source of errors that can occur from trying to create JSON output by hand.

```
final JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
while (rs.next()) {
   ja.put(new JSONObject()
       .put("Ausgaben", rs.getString("Ausgaben"))
       .put("vom",      rs.getString("vom"))
       .put("Preis",    rs.getString("Preis")));
}
response.getWriter().print(new JSONObject()
    .put("aaData", ja)
    .put("iTotalRecords", zeilen)
    .toString());
```

This will output something like `{"iTotalRecords":3,"aaData:[{"Ausgaben":"...","vom":"...","Preis":"..."},...]}`

I'd also recommend sending an error back to the user if an exception occurs, rather than silently ignore it.

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO: log the exception
    // this is our fault, let the user know we failed
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem lies in the implementation of the `Setzen` class. I'm sure the `setXXX()` methods don't append data but rather overwrite the data last written.

Also, if on Java 7, consider using `try-with-resources`, but this is unrelated to your question.